# Google sign in with private domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-api, appdomain

I am trying to create an Oauth2 with Google and it works well, the problem is when I am using my private domain to access my website, then when I try to sign in with Google and "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth" is request is showing me a blank site where the Google Accounts should be displayed.

I think it could be because when I am going to my website through my private domain the server is using the default URL to request it and not through my private domain.

I let an image about what I do describe:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to configure the NS and then it works